# Docker alpine, imagecreatefromjpeg doesn't work, imagecreatefrompng does

Tags: php, dockerfile, alpine-linux, imagecreatefrompng, imagecreatefromjpg

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql    
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache --update linux-headers ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \
    && apk add libzip-dev \
       freetype-dev \
       libjpeg-turbo-dev \
       jpeg-dev \
       libpng-dev \
       icu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
       exif \
       mysqli \
       pdo \
       pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache


# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl
```

When I run phpinfo() I get:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
PNG Support     enabled
libPNG Version  1.6.40
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support     enabled
BMP Support     enabled
TGA Read Support    enabled
```

However, when I run the following piece of php code to check the imagecreatefromjpeg and imagecreatefrompng functions I get `function imagecreatefromjpeg does not exist, function imagecreatefrompng exists`, indicating that for some reason jpeg images are not supported. Why could that be?

```
if(function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg')) {
  echo "function imagecreatefromjpeg exists<br />";
}else {
  echo "function imagecreatefromjpeg does not exist<br />";
}

if(function_exists('imagecreatefrompng')) {
  echo "function imagecreatefrompng exists<br />";
}else {
  echo "function imagecreatefrompng does not exist<br />";
}
```

Comment: Typo: you are installing `gd` twice (lines 16-17: `&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd` and line 25 `RUN docker-php-ext-install gd`). By doing so, the second install overrides the first one, and since the second one does not configure it to use JEPG, then, the function does not work anymore. The correct way to configure and install it is the one present at lines 16-17, so, just remove the line 25 and you'll be good to go.